# C++ can't write constructor for child class

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

**Problem solved! Thank you for help.**

I'm writing scheduler for my program. I have got 2 classes: `task_timepoint` and `task_period`. `task_period` is a derived class of `task_timepoint`.

I wrote constructor for `task_timepoint`, but when I start writing constructor for `task_period` I've got errors that I can't solve.

`scheduler.hpp`:

```
#ifndef SCHEDULER_H
#define SCHEDULER_H

#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

namespace schelduler{
    using namespace schelduler;
    using namespace boost::posix_time;

    class task_timepoint{
        protected:
            ptime run_time; //Time at(after) that task_function should run
            std::function<void(void)> task_function; //Function that should be run at specified time

        public:
            task_timepoint(ptime run_time, std::function<void(void)> task_function);
    };

    class task_period : public task_timepoint{
        private:
            time_duration run_period;

        public:
            task_period(time_duration run_period, std::function<void(void)> task_function);
    };
}
 #endif
```

`scheduler.cpp`:

```
#include "scheduler.hpp"

using namespace schelduler;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

task_timepoint::task_timepoint(ptime run_time, std::function<void(void)> task_function)
{
    task_timepoint::run_time = run_time;
    task_timepoint::task_function = task_function;
}

task_period::task_period(time_duration run_period, std::function<void(void)> task_function)
{
    this->run_period = run_period;
    //task_period::task_function = task_function;
}
```

Errors:

```
/home/dm3ch/Workspace/Refregiration_Telemetry/Device/src/scheduler.cpp: In constructor ‘schelduler::task_period::task_period(boost::posix_time::time_duration, std::function<void()>)’:
/home/dm3ch/Workspace/Refregiration_Telemetry/Device/src/scheduler.cpp:12:91: error: no matching function for call to ‘schelduler::task_timepoint::task_timepoint()’
 task_period::task_period(time_duration run_period, std::function<void(void)> task_function)
                                                                                           ^
/home/dm3ch/Workspace/Refregiration_Telemetry/Device/src/scheduler.cpp:12:91: note: candidates are:
/home/dm3ch/Workspace/Refregiration_Telemetry/Device/src/scheduler.cpp:6:1: note: schelduler::task_timepoint::task_timepoint(boost::posix_time::ptime, std::function<void()>)
 task_timepoint::task_timepoint(ptime run_time, std::function<void(void)> task_function)
 ^
/home/dm3ch/Workspace/Refregiration_Telemetry/Device/src/scheduler.cpp:6:1: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
In file included from /home/dm3ch/Workspace/Refregiration_Telemetry/Device/src/scheduler.cpp:1:0:
/home/dm3ch/Workspace/Refregiration_Telemetry/Device/include/scheduler.hpp:12:11: note: schelduler::task_timepoint::task_timepoint(const schelduler::task_timepoint&)
     class task_timepoint{
           ^
/home/dm3ch/Workspace/Refregiration_Telemetry/Device/include/scheduler.hpp:12:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/home/dm3ch/Workspace/Refregiration_Telemetry/Device/include/scheduler.hpp:12:11: note: schelduler::task_timepoint::task_timepoint(schelduler::task_timepoint&&)
/home/dm3ch/Workspace/Refregiration_Telemetry/Device/include/scheduler.hpp:12:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Refregiration_Telemetry-Device.dir/src/scheduler.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Refregiration_Telemetry-Device.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: "task_period is a derived class of task_period." !!??!?!

Comment: Edit your question and post relevant code and errors here.

Comment: I will not follow any external links to a small example at all! Please post your code here and please give us an idea which error messages you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `task_period` constructor tries to call the default constructor for the `task_timepoint` base class. You need to call it explicitly like this:

```
task_period::task_period(time_duration run_period, std::function<void(void)> task_function)
    : task_timepoint{run_period, task_function},
      run_period{run_period}
{}
```

Comment: But what should I do, if i can't set all parametrs for task_timepoint constructor?

Comment: If you can't set all parameters for `task_timepoint` you need to think about what data is intrinsic to the class and what is incidental. Can `task_timepoint` exist without some of that information? If so, create another constructor which takes the subset which you absolutely need. If not, maybe you aren't creating your `task_timepoint` objects at a suitable time.